# While explicitly instantiating vector<someType>, what is the someType default constructor used for?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

It's an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th Edition*:

> Exercise 16.26: Assuming NoDefault is a class that does not have a
>   default constructor, can we explicitly instantiate `vector<NoDefault>`?
>   If not, why not? P.677

I know it doesn't compile if class `NoDefault` has no default constructor, but can not explain the reason. Can anyone tell me how is the default constructor used while explicitly instantiating `template class std::vector<NoDefault>` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 introduces a new constructor, `vector(size_type n)`, and "obviously" that constructor can't be instantiated unless the `value_type` is default-constructible. It was `vector(size_type n, const T & = T(), const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())` in C++03, but they changed it to two separate constructors. A similar change was made to `resize()`.

In GCC and as far as I know also per the standard: the `vector` template can be at least *implicitly* instantiated without the elements being default constructible. Implicit template class instantiation only instantiates the member functions you use.

In C++03 only the default arguments use default construction. You can explicitly instantiate the template, but you won't be able to call those functions without providing a value for that parameter.

So I'm pretty sure that change is what prevents `vector<NoDefault>` being explicitly instantiated in C++11 (and I suppose the allocator type needs to be default-constructible too). But I might have missed something. It seems a little odd to make that change given that it introduces this backward incompatibility. There's probably a proposal somewhere that justifies it if you want a deeper reason why this *no longer* works as opposed to just why this *doesn't* work :-)

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the wrong section. It's not required for the type to be default-constructible.

Answer (score 3):

> While explicitly instantiating `std::vector<someType>`, what is the someType default constructor used for?

It's used to construct the elements of the array when resizing the `std::vector`. For example:

```
std::vector<T> vector(10);
```

will default construct 10 elements of type `T`.

Comment: I thought that the capacity of a vector was just a way to "preallocate" space for it, does it initialize the elements with the default constructor??

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense. Resize works that way. It should be made clear in the answer, it seems like "reserving" also needs the default constructor

Comment: @SteveJessop, how is it supposed to reserve the space without resizing the internal array?

Comment: @Jeffery: it calls the `allocate()` function on the allocator to get raw space, then it calls `construct()` many times to copy-construct (in C++03) or move-construct (in C++11) from the old buffer to the new buffer a number of elements equal to the `size()`.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, the default constructor is required to create vector of objects. However, if one were to create a classic dynamic array (contiguous area of memory), it would be possible to address the lack of a default constructor using the placement new syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(int a): a(a) {}
    int a;
};

int main() {
    void* mem = operator new[](10*sizeof(Foo));
    Foo* ptr = static_cast<Foo*>(mem);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        new(&ptr[i])Foo(i);
        std::cout << ptr[i].a;
    }
    return 0;
}
```