# Array initialization of objects without operator =, copy constructor or default constructor and run-time arguments

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, c++14

### Disclaimer

I'm trying to allocate an array of objects that are neither copy constructible, assignable nor has a default constructor. The objects have arguments that are determined at run time. I know that you can solve this problem by having an array of pointers or cleverly using placement new but I'm more interested in if this is possible to do cleanly with C++11 (1y) magic. **So please, this is purely of theoretical interest so avoid trying to solve "my problem" by offering a work around.**

### The code...

...So the question is: Is there a way to make the following work in C++11 or C++14:

```
class X{
public:
  explicit X(int a){...}
  X(const X&) = delete;
  void operator = (const X&) = delete;
private:
  ...
};

class Y{
public:
  Y(const std::vector<int>& args) {
    x = new X[]{args};
  }
  ~Y(){
    delete [] x;
  }
private:
  X* x;
};
```

### Criteria

Specifically I'm looking for a solution/construct that meets the following criteria:

- X is not copy constructible.
- X is not assignable.
- X does not have a default no-argument constructor (construction has intended side-effects).
- The arguments to X's constructor are not known until run time.
- All instances of X must be laid out contiguously in memory.
- X must be properly destructed when the array is deleted from it's base pointer (or if an intermediate class is used, when the intermediate object is destructed). This rules out array of pointers and naivë use of placement new.

### Edit / Addendum

I forgot to mention that move constructor is not available. In the actual case at hand, `X` spawns a worker thread and is executing in the context of `this` of the initially constructed object, any attempt to use a move constructor will corrupt the state of the executing thread.

Comment: Use `vector` and `emplace_back`.

Comment: @Fernandes Re: edit. I used the term "C++1x" specifically to mean answers in C++11 or C++14. Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts It was neither a grammatical or spelling error, nor was it a clarification (you changed my meaning).

Comment: Please use "C++11 or C++14" then. "C++1x" was once used to mean "the soon to be released version of C++ that used to be referred to as C++0x but will now be released in the second decade of the third millennium". It does not help clarity.

Comment: (a) The edit fixed a noticeable problem with your question. The entire C++ community, including the standard working group, uses C++1y to mean C++14. It never means C++11. And C++1x simply doesn't exist, but where it does, it is ambiguous due to C++0x's history. So your intent was misrepresented until Martinho very kindly fixed it for you. A "thank you" would be appropriate. (b) It's not _your_ post; this is a Q&A database, not your personal programming helpdesk.

Comment: (c) No consent is required: you explicitly gave up all claims to that by posting under the CC By-SA 3.0 licence, and reading the FAQ that explains all about how this site works. Hope that alleviates some confusion for you. Also, (d) don't be so rude.

Comment: Anyway, back to the topic of the question, use `std::vector::emplace_back`, although this is not strictly initialization (although you can use  helper function to prepare the vector for you, then move it into your data member). But it allows you to fill in an array while meeting the other constraints.

Comment: The first edit (which I backed) changed the intended meaning of my question from meaning "C++11 and C++14 (1y)" (as it said in the introduction) to meaning only "C++11".  This edit was done abruptly and wrongly and without asking for clarification first. I agree I don't hold any rights to the question and no consent is *required* however it is common courtesy to ask or at least notify the author first.

Comment: @EmilyL. the website notifies you automatically. You changed it back. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza emplace_back() will not work as there is no copy ctor. Atleast that's what gcc tells me. I told Fernandes to hold his edits and not be so darn quick, and Lightness got his pants in a twist because of it. No problem.

Comment: Probably may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525169/while-explicitly-instantiating-vectorsometype-what-is-the-sometype-default-co

Comment: @EmilyL. Ah OK, you need to add a *move* copy constructor, then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class that is neither copyable nor movable, nor has a default constructor, cannot be held in a standard container (doesn't meet the requirements) or a variable-sized array allocation (which only allows argument specification for a fixed number of elements).

This means you need to allocate raw memory instead and use placement new to construct the objects. You can wrap this in a fixed-space vector class.

```
template <typename T>
class fixed_capacity_vector {
public:
  using size_type = std::size_t;

  fixed_capacity_vector(size_type capacity)
    : data_(::operator new(capacity * sizeof(T)), size_(), capacity_(capacity)
  {}

  fixed_capacity_vector(const fixed_capacity_vector&) = delete;
  fixed_capacity_vector(fixed_capacity_vector&&) = delete;
  fixed_capacity_vector& operator =(const fixed_capacity_vector&) = delete;
  fixed_capacity_vector& operator =(fixed_capacity_vector&&) = delete;

  ~fixed_capacity_vector() {
    for (size_type i = 0; i < size_; ++i) data_[i].~T();
    ::operator delete(data_);
  }

  template <typename... Args>
  T& emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
    if (size_ == capacity_) throw out_of_range();
    new (data_ + size_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ++size_;
    return data_[size_-1];
  }

private:
  T* data_;
  size_type size_;
  size_type capacity_;
};
```

Comment: I'd recommend doing destruction from last to first, as destruction is usually performed in the the reverse order of construction everywhere in the language and standard library (`std::vector` does this too). Be careful with unsigned types in decreasing loops, though.

Comment: Yeah, the unsigned thing is why I did it forward. In a real implementation, I'd have iterators and reverse iterators and I would use those.

Comment: There is no *contiguous* standard container that can store a non-copyable, non-moveable non-default constructible type.  Relax the contiguous requirement and you can use a deque or a list.

Comment: Whats wrong with `while(size_) data[--size_].~T();` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::vector` and its `emplace_back` function if you make `X` at least movable.

```
class X{
public:
  explicit X(int){}
  X(X&&) = default;
  X(const X&) = delete;
  void operator = (const X&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<X> xs;
    xs.emplace_back(0);
    xs.emplace_back(1);
    xs.emplace_back(2);
    xs.emplace_back(3);
}
```

(If you declare a copy constructor, even if that declaration deletes it, the compiler will not automatically generate any special move member, so you need to explicitly request them)

This basically boils down to the "array with placement new" strategy, but all abstracted away into high-level notions.

If you cannot make use of a movable type, you have to implement a vector-like class that pre-allocates storage and never reallocates. There is nothing similar in the standard library.

Comment: I knew I forgot something, I can't use the move constructor due to side effects in the constructor (starting a worker thread executing code in the context of `this`). Added a clarification to the post.

Comment: FWIW, the move constructor is only required for compilation. If you call `reserve` beforehand it will not be used. If you really want to avoid it, you'll have to write a vector-like class that never reallocates.

Comment: Then I run the risk of inadvertently using that move constructor somewhere in a daft moment. ;\ Sure I can just throw and catch it at compile time but I don't like that.

Comment: Must `this` be used as context, can not a member pointer to a struct be used as the context, which then can actually be moved in the move constructor?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have to keep track of the constructed elements by hand, but you can use `allocator` to help:

```
class Y{
public:
  Y(const std::vector<int>& args):
    alloc{},
    n{args.size()},
    x{alloc.allocate(n)}
  {
    auto end = x;
    try {
      for (auto arg: args)
        alloc.construct(end++, arg);
    } catch (...) {
      while (end != x)
        alloc.destroy(--end);
      alloc.deallocate(x, n);
      throw;
    }
  }
  ~Y() {
    for (auto end = std::next(x, n); end != x; --end)
      alloc.destroy(end);
    alloc.deallocate(x, n);
  }
private:
  std::allocator<X> alloc;
  const std::size_t n;
  const X *x;
};
```

Comment: I would inherit privately from `std:: allocator` to take advantage of the empty base optimization. And probably parameterize on `X` and the allocator type because everything deserves to be a template ;)

Comment: Also, it's not necessary to store both the size and end pointer, since the entire range is always initialized in the constructor. Either one will suffice.

Comment: @Casey if one of the `X`s throws on construction, we need to destroy only the previous elements.  If `X` was nothrow constructible from `int` then, yes, we could eliminate the end pointer.

Comment: If one of the `X`s throws the construction won't complete, so the destructor won't run. You need a `try/catch/throw` and manual cleanup or encapsulation in another class that just handles deallocation/destruction.

Comment: @Casey of course! Fixed. This is why writing exception-safe containers is *hard*.