# How can I store a variable number of objects which are not default constructible, copyable, or movable?

Tags: c++

I want a contiguous array of objects (number of objects known at runtime), but the objects are not default constructible, copyable, or movable.

Background:

I'm developing a data processing program. At the start of execution, an input object specifies exactly how many Data objects need to be created for processing. Each Data object owns other resources and also references memory from the input object. During run time, I repeatedly loop over the data objects to perform tasks for each object.

Ideally, I want a contiguous chunk of memory containing all Data objects for the sake of performance. I originally achieved this during development with std::vector by reserving memory for all Data objects, then calling emplace_back however many times were needed.

I added a destructor to Data for development trace data while debugging and my code no longer compiled because the move constructor, which is necessary for std::vector, is now implicitly deleted.

Truthfully, the Data objects should not be copied or moved. Even though the move constructor was implicitly defaulted before I added the destructor, it was never called because no moves are truly needed. The most impact the move constructor has is that it adds extra code to the binary that never gets called. While it doesn't harm performance to make Data movable, I do prefer to have those operators deleted to enforce that those objects aren't copied or moved. That way I know immediately if I'm doing something that I didn't intend to do.

I'm looking for an idiomatic solution.

I think part of the problem is that the objects/data are so tightly coupled. If Data were made default constructible and pointer to the input data was set post construction, I could use a `unique_ptr<Data[]>`.

I've also tried making a fixed size vector which seems to work. I found eastl::fixed_vector, but it seems to need the capacity defined at compile time rather than run time and requires a movable object.

Simple example code here:
[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISRqkrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxP4AHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxkkl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn4Btpj2RQwNTQQlkTFxibaNza25HQrjA2FD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMYcjeWADUJrtutHgzZ9gmGgCCewdHmKfnbCwkAJ43d49m%2BwYhy8JzObgAbrUiMRfg8nkCXm83E4ZsRMKxYY8HukAF6YAD6BGOwHxeHQZyscOxBGIXgcxwAIkxGn8TAB2Sn3Y7cxnMpgQNAMGbHMIEcwANhFy2OIGOLFJ7IseHZDNIctJ5I51msJLJKr%2BPNOHNOD0Nhpm6BAKHWRLBYNOZjMyDRzNe5jMSPt8rJnvOxzAOwArG4GAGKQaefrTTyAH5MxoQaUMVCYVRbZJEk1cyNa6Nm44Wq1oLy287291YVGoL4Oj12v3e9C%2Btz%2BoMhsO7TmGqNY7Pc%2BP8wXCgcS6VnBnHLD0AiYcN53kssyS1DJOLMkjjgUCYd80dvCdTzAzud9hf8kdLvfjyddI%2BzzvHAD0j/3N6oTC8tCJAHc6LRjmItCoN%2BxwEAgryQg4JDHJgLDJAYWz4tETDIAA1hG/a7kuxwrmu0Kbhe4pXrsB63senasvOQ5EqKErqsqFHzriBJEo2J76oxvainKTBhBA3FNMAyBqsgCBNAAVABxDAOCJiBlYgYMssrK5qehYgJB%2BHnCOuzYMckEnoa/DEMc/GCCKr4aBSFn2oJpgPtqlh4Mp86KhhZrPpBAB0sHwShBLIWhEB2cpD7PvpULQWiACOXh4GiCiTnyIqJZ84JMNE9DuT27nhVylzCmgcF0JgiXRCWKXHMmRKCo4wBeOsChqmJiWpjSTDHF44TIFsChNDWgGoKIPRNQBDDkvO4UtXKJCvKgkLEOBTBNt%2BCAlccQErmEwBeccACSPEDYl35dP%2BwCoMcv5gQBEVQSZqBUJ1DB4LFrwZjCTEEJaIAFWK2m7rpG1XH9XY8sZpncXglnWVDtnSfZFgOlYTkuaebnzoaz6/T5cEIQFKGocF8OhYj4XfiQqEKNlbIMpRvaYy%2B6ApgooYcD%2BFOmcm%2BliD61G0ndqMM%2BpXUvV4BLvWCI7yXJtOAyLr34k0xBMDW17qSwTCoQS8ti5Lu7S4pNxE0JJN0wzxw0KomBNsxk5fMwLB4KItC0ANLtDa6TaaRun380SlvW/i3sfWjqn5tyAfoEHkXEBAzGElVPj4ugfJjhjPKyjM/T4g9ye7saWeOMg%2BKiNc/2NOJRsa%2B7yAQAwScp40xyScxD0QAOyydyqpDuWarg51QecshyWfNAPQ9MN3Wbh9y/e5x83yKqPBDj43HXWIn8pryq08z%2Bjp4z3gj1x7Mq/JeO171y772CzPOag3fZpgcQwEFl9VrIVHg2mFqNOGY/RpabpxzEAg%2BkZgFnjor5PGSECZbiFDRQQdFnK93vqg/MR9TJz0Hmvfc15sH4gXsQL4t9H77wAU/BAL8QLqRtOPZWRhZxakdDaHCj1ojrHGlTR0HEH53xyhAw0aICAbAYM3cIIEIAEO3pYaw0oRwcmVH/Tie8/5UjAdyGMkdo53UTOgo0fCZ7g3bnySShA4ivmXmfFkD5zEmXtNIgGiNHJKhnMQUh/Cw4UJ5HYgAtDcOMfI9EqIAT2ChVA0SYBPtnXOa9TYQIERos8klqJvxiTgpx%2BiBySUcTYwxPJsnHFSQQohPwQncl4WbMGeArZR2DhbGpgdILG2QPEtG85jGQ2hrYpEUkhLWRcSg1yXj8zaO8tA/ysCgohX/hUtRjwaYcFWLQTggZeB%2BA4FoUgqBOBuBcQWdYmw3QAh4KQAgmglmrFQnkLyGhJBcA0OKNkbJxRcASI8gAnAkQM%2BhOCSHWRc7ZnBeAKBAIEc5mylmkDgLAJARVkglTIBQLcxV6DxGAFwXYZhSBYHBE7TAAA1PAmBvwAHlVwbNOTQL8cRQUQGiIC6IYR%2BqcFOUy5gxDSXRG0FCVlvAipsEEKShgrtAVYHKsANwgFQXcF4FgDWRhxCQpxfFKEeBIQyq2amWoJZthbNFF0QFlxojK2IR4LAgKaR4BYHy1YVADDAAUESkl5LGB8pkIIEQYh2BSA9fIJQahAW6C4PoQwxgXH6DwNEUFkBVgrhGpwXxFpxymFkZYAExxfGkt2LweacRiBklKvAVYNQ6jOCkeNSYfgQ0hHmGUCoegCgZAEFWxtaRm0MEGPWkYIbS09D6BMTwbQ9B9vqLMLtwx4i9tmK26d/QJ2LCnSWw5WwJDLNWQC5VOyODHFUAkcUvjxSSGJD1Y4mKvIeggLgQg0E9hcGWLwCFWhO6kGuUuLy4ozCBkDF8j5dzvkfPFPu35HB/mkA2Vs7dIKwVnIuasGFiAQA2mSCWcglB4WIoiKwbYe6D1HpPcgM9uwL28GtjegtloQ38E9c7H10hqP%2BpUOoZVwbSDfmVskW1IG1ngcBdu0lJYUNEgeru/dh7j1CUI%2Bey9HhUUWLvQ%2B2DkKX3XN2MRtTGnNNaZA2BiDubgW2Bg0%2By5IGzCbsgwZ4zL6FrpGcJIIAA)

Comment: Are these "data objects" polymorphic? Do they have a common base class? Or are there only one type of "data objects"? Either way, a vector of (smart) pointers comes to mind. On the other hand, if you want the object themselves stored contiguously, then an array of bytes, large enough to store all the "objects", and then do your own "allocation" and placement-new to put the object into this array. Be careful about alignment though, make sure that all object types are padded so they can actually be stored contiguously without padding in the byte-array itself.

Comment: Some thoughts: is your code wrong or unusable if objects aren't stored contiguously? You might be overthinking performance, try using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>>` and see how far you get. Also, `std::vector<Data>` _does_ call `Data`'s move or copy constructor when reallocating e.g. during a series of `push_back`/`emplace_back` calls. Worrying about binary bloat due to a single move constructor also shouldn't be a concern unless you're limited to a few KB of memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array initialization of objects without operator =, copy constructor or default constructor and run-time arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599749/array-initialization-of-objects-without-operator-copy-constructor-or-default)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for 'placement new' (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). You can allocate 'raw' memory then force the construction of an object somewhere in that memory.

Comment: In my case, there is only one type of data object. I have considered using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>>` as well as rolling my own fixed vector using placement new. Those are viable options, but what leads me to this question is that it seems like there should be a simple idiomatic way to have the same behavior as a fixed vector (as if a `std::vector<Data>` just worked) without having to jump through the hoops. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Data>>` may be the most idiomatic way even if it has some additional performance overhead.

Comment: @Lambo *"it seems like there should be a simple idiomatic way"* -- Keep in mind that the standard library is intended to cover common scenarios. The less common scenarios are often skipped or relegated to future versions of the standard. How common is it to have objects that are not default constructible, copyable, or movable? Personally, I would not expect a "simple, idiomatic way" to deal with an uncommon case, especially one so restricted. Such a way might exist, but I would not say it *should* exist.

Comment: You cannot have a chunk of memory that is (1) contiguous (2) can grow indefinitely and (3) can grow in place. Pick two.

Comment: The idiomatic solution is to let these objects be movable, and use vector

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI it does not need to grow at all in this case.

Comment: If it doesn't grow at all then it's a `std::array`. If you need to add elements one by one, which I suspect you do, you need a fixed capacity vector. It grows but not beyond its fixed capacity. There is one in boost, called `static_vector`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I do need to add elements one by one since they're not default constructible, but both `std::array` and `static_vector` like `eastl::fixed_vector` require the the number of elements is known at compile time.

Comment: @Caleth I think that's the right answer, but I really wish I could delete the move constructor to have total control. (Just like I would like to delete implicit conversion from C array to pointer if only I could!)

Answer (score 0):

If you drop the contiguous data requirement, `std::deque` might work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace {
struct X {
  X(int) {}
  X() = delete;
  X(const X&) = delete;
  X(X&&) = delete;
};
}  // namespace

int main() {
  std::deque<X> dq;
  dq.emplace_back(1);
  dq.emplace_back(2);
  dq.emplace_back(3);
}
```